# C# SQLite-Net Extensions 'SQLiteConnection does not contain a definition for CreateTable'

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite-net-pcl

I am trying to use the SQLite-Net Extensions NuGet package in a WinForms application. I have included a reference within a class and am trying to follow the documentation found here:

https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

However, in the example, there are a few things that are left out.

```
var db = Utils.CreateConnection();
db.CreateTable<Stock>();
```

There is no Utils class, so I figured I would just create my own SQLiteConnection object and the CreateTable extension method would become usable, but that turned out to be false.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i'd recommend using the package from the SQLite Dev team: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: @JohnB I have System.Data.SQLite added to my project already, plus the SQLite-Net Extensions package to extend the SQLiteConnection object.

Comment: they may not play nicely together...

Comment: the extension say it needs `sqlite-net-plc (>=1.4.118)`

Comment: it's all a bit of a mess in the sqllite space so i can understand how easy it would be to get packages mixed up

Comment: @JohnB Hey John thanks for the help.  It turns out I had System.Data.SQLite and SqliteExtensions both in my using statements, but did not have the Sqlite namespace from the sqlite-net package you mentioned imported as well.  It is working now.

Comment: cool - glad to hear